# Postgres date range insertion using Dapper and Npgsql

Tags: postgresql, dapper, npgsql, date-range

I'm trying to use Dapper to insert a date range into my Postgres database, using code like this:

```
string INSERT_DATE_RANGE = @"INSERT INTO datetable (daterange) VALUES('[@dateRangeStart, @dateRangeBegin]')";

.... (standard connection stuff)

var startDate = DateTime.Now;
var endDate = DateTime.MaxValue;

connection.Execute(INSERT_DATE_RANGE, new { @dateRangeStart = startDate, @dateRangeBegin = endDate });
```

This gives me the following error:

> 22007: invalid input syntax for type date: "@dateRangeStart"

I suspect this is because the parameters I'm trying to replace are inside the single quotes.  If I remove the quotes however, I get a different error message:

> 42601: syntax error at or near "["

Any suggestions?  I could just concatenate the string but I would prefer not to use that approach as it opens things up to a possible SQL injection.

Comment: @mcNets Does Dapper provide a way to do this?  From what I've read it's better to pass in parameters along with the SQL statement rather than use something like String.Format

Comment: Maybe this article can help: https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/212274/A-Look-at-Dapper-NET

Comment: Hmm, one quick idea: why not try to insert the range directly, i.e. provide a single NpgsqlRange<DateTime> parameter which would contain the start and end? Even if this works it's worth understanding why your example doesn't, though.

Comment: @ShayRojansky I tried this out as well, and got this: The member effectiveDateRange of type NpgsqlTypes.NpgsqlRange`1[[NpgsqlTypes.NpgsqlDate, Npgsql, Version=3.0.5.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=5d8b90d52f46fda7]] cannot be used as a parameter value

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the [constructor function](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/rangetypes.html#RANGETYPES-CONSTRUCT) for the `daterange` type, i.e.:

```
INSERT INTO datetable (daterange) VALUES (daterange(@dateRangeStart, @dateRangeBegin, '[]'))
```

Comment: When prepare and bindParam to be used for php language: it should be  $sql = "insert into schd_range(date_range) values (daterange(:fDate, :tDate, '[]'))";